# Why does visual studio not make an exe file when using the windows service template and publishing it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, windows-services, publishing

When publishing a console application, I have a lot of settings that I can change when deploying. I can choose between azure, clickonce, docker, normal folder and I am also able to choose the target runtime and the deployment mode.


But when using the windows service template for my project and I want to publish this, then the GUI looks totally different. I am not able to choose the settings that I had with the console application. I am not even able to choose the target runtime nor the deployment mode. Despite all that when I continue, the folder where my windows service is deployed doesn't contain an exe file of my application. It contains the setup.exe, but that is not what I want. I want the exe file of the windows service itself.


Does anyone have an idea why the settings are different and why it only gives a setup.exe?


**Here below the settings of the publish console application as it should be.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here below the settings of the publish windows service template which looks totally different and with fewer settings.**
[image]
[image]

Comment: if a WindowsService and a Console Application were the same why would you need two different templates? I can't make sense of your post. Why do you expect the same settings and output?

Comment: @Piglet Well, a windows service is an executable isn't it? You need the executable that will make the windows service. The only thing that changes with the windows service template is that the basic code is already written for you.

Comment: if you just want the executable build it. I don't know much about windows service development but I would argue that it is some special kind of executable. you cannot just execute it. it requires installation. at least that's what it says when I try to execute one. so why should you publish the executable on its own and why should the developer make any settings? I guess Microsoft knows how to publish a windows service better than anyone else.  still I don't understand why you expect it to be configured the same as a console application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question very well, I suggest you review the files created by the publishing process.

1.In Solution Explorer, select Show All Files.

2.In the project folder, expand bin/Release/net6.0/publish.

If you are publishing console applications in visual studio, you can refer to this document, which has detailed publishing steps.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-6-0#publish-the-app

Comment: How do you publish a windows service then? In summary, what I want to make is an executable where the user just have to double click it. The executable will then install the windows service for the user.

Answer (score 0):

After writing the window service class, do the following:

1. Right click and select Add Installer

[image]

2. The ProjectInstaller.cs file is added to the project, and the view in this file will automatically add two components serviceProcessInstaller1 and serviceInstaller1

[image]

3.Set the main properties of serviceInstaller1, ServiceName: the unique system service identifier, used when executing the command in the command, use to identify a window service. Set StartType, if it is Manual, start manually, stop by default, if it is Automatic, it will start automatically.[image]

4.Rebuild the project

5.Open Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio with administrative credentials. In Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio, navigate to the folder that contains your project's output (by default, the \bin\Debug subdirectory of your project).
Enter the following command:`installutil MyNewService.exe`

6.Start and run the service. In Windows, open the Services desktop app. Press Windows+R to open the Run box, enter services.msc, and then press Enter or select OK.

Comment: I don't want the user to put commands in cmd. I want the user to just double click an executable and the service will be installed.

Comment: If the user can install the service by double-clicking the executable, I guess this method is not a good idea. Requires the InstallUtil.exe command-line utility or PowerShell to quickly install the service app.

Comment: you can check this document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services